# Rails: id field is nil when calling Model.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am a little confused about the auto-increment id field in rails. I have a rails project with a simple schema. When i check the development.sqlite3 I can see that all of my tables have an id field with auto increment.

```
CREATE TABLE "messages" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "text" text, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime);
```

But when I call `Message.new` in the console, the resulting object has an `id` of `nil`.

```
>> a = Message.new
=> #<Message id: nil, text: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Shouldn't the `id` come back populated?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, that's the correct behavior. When you create an object via `new` (as in your example), Rails doesn't persist it to the database (just in memory).

If you do `Message.create`, or `Message.save` like **theIV** said, then the `id` will be populated.

Comment: I am assigning id to another column as well while building, its nil even after save.
Example: `user.orders.build({custum_id: "CUST_#{self.id}"})`
also due to some reason I can not make it primary key. any solution?

Answer (score 5):

Like fig said,

```
n = Movie.new
n.save
=> true
```

means that it is saved and will be given an ID.  Alternatively,

```
n = Movie.create!
```

automatically saves and stores it in the database and gives it an ID with one line of code.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the `id` field only gets assigned on `save`s, not on `new`s.

Answer (score 0):

All answers above are correct. To add to them, calling the `#save` method on an instance will return `true` if it was able to insert into database and `false` if it wasn't successful. Using the `::create` method will make a new instance of your model, and will call `#save` on it.

You can also use the `#save!` or `::create!` methods. The difference is that these will raise an error (as opposed to returning boolean) if they were not successful in their insertion to the database.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I called Model.create(event_id) with constant value (6) that was NOT the event's actual id. There was no error, and an Active Record Model was returned with other attributes, except id was nil.

I fixed my bug after some hours of debugging by changing the value to the actual reference id of the existing Event.id (as it was previously). Note that you might get this error if you have SQL foreign constraint to some other table, but you are using incorrect id for the reference.